# Algorithm to compute the Variance of the signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, algorithms

I have 6.4 sec recording of a discrete signal on 40Hz frequency (256 values).

How can I compute the variance of the signal?
Please, share an algorithm in pseudo-code or in an actual programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [sample variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance):

$$
s^2 = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (x_n - \mu_x)^2
$$

where the mean, $\mu_x$, is given by

$$
\mu_x = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n.
$$

The $\frac{1}{N-1}$ factor should be used to account for the bias that is otherwise there if $\frac{1}{N}$ is used. One way to think about this is the sample variance is computed from $N-1$ *differences* between samples, rather than $N$ samples.

Comment: I am measuring the magnitude of the acceleration vector of triaxial accelerometer. Every value of my set is the  magnitude of the [x,y,z] vector. Do you still think, I should be getting the sample variance?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't matter much how the data is generated. If you're estimating a variance from (effectively) an infinite, or at least large, population, then it's the sample variance you want.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. I will mark your post as an answer as soon as I have the "reputation" to do it. :)

Comment: Thanks! Odd. It's your question.. you should be able to mark the answer.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I can actually mark it as an answer, but can't upvote it yet. Marked! Thank you!

Comment: :-) You're welcome! Welcome to DSP.SE! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [Sample Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) $s^2$ of a signal $\mathbf{y}$ with sample average $\mu$ may be computed as:
$$
\begin{align*}
s^2 &= \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \mu)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^N \left( \mu^2 - 2 \mu y_i + y_i^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{N-1} \left[ N \mu^2 - 2 \mu \sum_{i=1}^N y_i + \sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2 \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{N-1} \left[ N \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right)^2 - 2 \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right) \sum_{i=1}^N y_i + \sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2 \right] &\left( \mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{N-1} \left[ N \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right)^2 - 2 N \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2 \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{N-1} \left[ -N \left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2 \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{N-1} \left[ -\frac{1}{N} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N y_i \right)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2 \right]
\end{align*}
$$

Below is an example in C++ code that implements the above equation.  It may not be completely optimized, but it should be fairly efficient:

```
double sample_variance(double *signal, unsigned int signal_length)
{
  double sum = 0.0;
  double sum2 = 0.0;
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<signal_length; i++)
  {
    sum += signal[i];
    sum2 += signal[i]*signal[i];
  }

  double N = (double)signal_length;
  return (sum2 - sum*sum/N)/(N-1.0);
}
```

Comment: I cooked up this little example, and came back to find Peter K. had already given a great answer.  I decided to add this anyway, since the question ask for an algorithm or code.

Comment: Are you sure "(sum2 - sum*sum/N)/(N-1.0)" is correct?... Seems like there is a $\sum \mu^2$ missing...

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond: I did a sanity check to make sure that the code was giving me the correct variance.  I will edit my answer to add my justification.  Let me know if it is wrong.

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond:  You were right that there was a problem with my formula.  Thanks for pointing it out.  It is now fixed in the code.

Comment: The comment wont let me put a big formula in here, so [here is it worked out](http://d.pr/i/bj9e). I think you had it right the first time.

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond:  Thanks again.  It turns out that my back-of-the-napkin math was better than my LaTeX math.  :)  I have reverted to the original C++ code, and updated the math.

Comment: Its quite clever! Have an upvote for this. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on what is [Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) and how to calculate it. If you are using Matlab then you can form a column matrix consisting of the 256 values and send it to the [var](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/var.html) function in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks for the link, although this was the first thing I checked out when I started researching. I suppose I need the Population Variance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance Is this correct?

Comment: No, the population variance assumes that you have measured every single one of the possible points to measure.  It sounds like you could sample another 256 points at a later point... so the original 256 points do not constitute the whole population.